# Drawing a ladder graph with Line and Table/Array

Tags: graphics

I want to programmatically draw a ladder graph like the one below:

[image]

I'd like to use Table to dynamically add steps.

My (lame) attempt so far:

```
Graphics@Line[Table[{i, j }, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 4}] , 
  VertexColors -> Black]
```

Comment: by the way, `FullForm[Normal[Show[GridGraph[{8, 2}]]]]`. interestingly, by converting to graphics with either `Show` or `FullGraphics`, you can move vertices around and the edges stay connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = 9;

Graphics[
  {Line[{{{1, 0}, {1, n}}, {{2, 0}, {2, n}}}], Line@#, PointSize[0.2], Point /@ #} & @
    Table[{x, y}, {y, n - 1}, {x, 2}]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
ladderF = SetProperty[EdgeDelete[GraphData[{"Ladder", #}],
     {1 <-> 2, (2 # - 1) <-> (2 #)}], {EdgeStyle -> Black, 
     VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> Thread[{1, 2, 2 # - 1, 2 #} -> 0]}] &;

ladderF@8
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1, who knew there is a special "Ladder" type graph included in the package. Offtopic: interesting name change...

Comment: @shrx, thank you for the vote.

Answer (score 8):

```
n = 10;
GridGraph[{n + 2, 2}, 
 EdgeStyle -> {1 <-> n + 3 -> Opacity[0], 
   n + 2 <-> 2 n + 4 -> Opacity[0]}, BaseStyle -> Black, 
 VertexShape -> {1 -> Null, n + 2 -> Null, n + 3 -> Null, 
   2 n + 4 -> Null}]
```

[image: ladder graph]